# How to click button or link in react, javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to ask how can I click the "search by parcel number" programatically using react or javascript or what language can trigger the onclick on the search by parcel number button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: just target it (in react you can use `useRef`) and whenever you want you can use `<elementPointer>.click()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `useRef` (if you have access to the element in your App)

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect, useRef} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const buttonRef = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("clicking with ref");
        buttonRef.current.click();
      }, 1500);
    }, []);
  
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
            <button ref={buttonRef} onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can use all the usual methods such as:

1. [getElemeentById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
2. [getElementsByClassname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

... etc

Answer (score 2):

You use use ref.

```
const parcelNumberSearchRef = useRef(null);
const addressSearchRef = useRef(null);
```

assuming you have your component

```
...
<div>
    <div ref={addressSearchRef}>Search By Address</div>
    <div ref={parcelNumberSearchRef}>Search By Parcel Number</div>
</div>
...

function someFunctionToBeCalledWhenYouWantToClick(){
    parcelNumberSearchRef.current.click()
}
```

and that's it